# An atexit for Bash

Tags: bash

I wrote the following [atexit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Cleanups-on-Exit.html) implementation for Bash

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

ATEXIT=()

function atexit_handler
{
  local EXPR
  for EXPR in "${ATEXIT[@]}"; do
    echo "evaluating $EXPR"
    eval "$EXPR" || true
  done
}

trap atexit_handler EXIT

function atexit ()
{
  local EXPR
  for EXPR in "$@"; do
    ATEXIT+=("$EXPR")
  done
}

atexit true
atexit false
atexit "echo bye"

false
```

I am wondering, if this is possible without the use of `eval`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible without the `eval`. A close candidate might be:

```
atexit_handler() {
  local EXPR
  for EXPR in "${ATEXIT[@]}"; do
    echo "evaluating $EXPR"
    $EXPR || true
  done
}
```

But this won't work with non-trivial expressions like this:

```
atexit 'for i in "a b" c; do echo $i; done'
```

---

Using the `function` keyword in function declaration like this is an outdated practice:

> ```
> function atexit_handler
> {
>   local EXPR
>   for EXPR in "${ATEXIT[@]}"; do
>     echo "evaluating $EXPR"
>     eval "$EXPR" || true
>   done
> }
> ```

Use the more modern style I wrote in the previous example above.

---

Instead of this:

> ```
>   for EXPR in "$@"; do
>     ATEXIT+=("$EXPR")
>   done
> ```

A simpler way to iterate over `$@`:

```
  for EXPR; do
    ATEXIT+=("$EXPR")
  done
```

But actually, as [@etan-reisner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28012/etan-reisner) pointed out in a comment, it's silly to loop here when you can add the entire arg list in one swift move:

```
ATEXIT+=("$@")
```

Comment: Why bother iterating over `"$@"` at all? Why not just splat it into the `()` directly? `ATEXIT+=("$@")`

Comment: Using `set -e` means it works even when the script is run "manually" (i.e. `bash myscript.sh`) which the shebang does not.

Comment: @EtanReisner spot on! Thanks for that. I added the first point to my answer and removed the second.

Comment: Emacs does not color the function names in sh-mode. Using the `function` keyword adds some syntax highlighting to functions.

Comment: At the time I posted this, I didn't know what `EXIT` really meant. Thanks @TobySpeight for pointing this out, dropped that point. (I fear I may have said things like this in other old answers too. I should probably search and verify all :-/)

Answer (score 2):

Still uses eval, but it seems cleaner to do:

```
atexit() {
        cmd="$1"
        eval set -- $(trap -p EXIT)
        trap "$cmd; $3" EXIT
}
```

To allow semi-colons (eg, `atexit "echo foo;"`) and aesthetic purity, you might like:

```
atexit() {
        cmd="${1%;}"
        eval set -- $(trap -p EXIT)
        trap "$cmd${3:+; }$3" EXIT
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: Nice idea. You should use quotes in case the trap commands contain special characters: `eval "set -- $(trap -p EXIT)"`. (Aside: `trap -p <sigspec>` is specific to bash. POSIX only specifies a way to display *all* the traps, by running `trap` with no arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for excavating this, but just found it and wanted to try.

Will offer what I can.

```
#! /bin/bash
```

This is no crime, but it's a tad more portable (if that matters at all to you) if you use

```
#! /bin/env bash
```

`env` itself is virtually always in `/bin`, though some installations move the interpreter binaries.

I don't personally like or use `set -e`. It doesn't give me as much control over what happens. Personally, I prefer `trap`s, something like this:

```
trap 'echo "ERROR $? at $0:$LINENO - [$BASH_COMMAND]"' err
```

Then I get useful feedback.

```
$: bogus
bash: bogus: command not found
ERROR 127 at /usr/bin/bash:73 - [bogus]
```

As for the `eval`, how about creating a controlled file to source at exit time?

```
atexit_handler() {
  tmp=$(mktemp)
  printf "%s\n" "${ATEXIT[@]}" >| $tmp
  trap 'echo "Error $? in exit handler when processing [$BASH_COMMAND]"' err
  . $tmp
}
```

This would allow for more arbitrarily complex possibilities, without really worsening the security risk of the `eval`, which isn't catastrophic if your code registers all the commands going into the handler anyway. It also leaves you the option of scheduling the cleanup of the file *with* the handler, so that if it succeeds it leaves no mess, but if it fails will abort and let you debug the file.

```
atexit true
atexit "echo bye"
atexit 'sing() { for i in do re me;do echo "$i"; done; }'
atexit sing
atexit false
atexit 'rm $tmp' # defer evaluation
```

I love this idea, btw. I may start using it. :)

Comment: I've never seen a `/bin/env` - on Debian-based systems at least, it's always in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: As long as it's working, I wouldn't sweat it. YMMV; even where I work, across a lot of systems, they are mostly all RHEL 6 or 7 and vaguely similar in structure, so it has rarely been an issue. It's just something I have been told to cultivate as a habit, and I have (anecdotally) had fewer issues since I started doing it. *shrug* :D

Comment: So RHEL have `/bin/env` *instead of* `/usr/bin/env`?  Or *as well as*? If it has both, then the latter would seem to be the safer choice.

Comment: Common to have it linked in both locations just in case. :)